# How to make hidden component clickable in AEM backend

Tags: adobe, aem

**NOTE: I'm unable to upload images due to company safety regulations.**

I have a pop-up experience fragment in AEM. The component has the functionality to be enabled/disabled by a checkbox (value activatePopup true/false).

In the HTML this is coded as:

```
<div data-sly-test="${properties.activatePopup}">POP UP CONTENT HERE</div>
```

So, it doesn't show if *properties.activatePopup* is false.

**PROBLEM:**
In the backend it also doesn't show. It is only reachable by selecting the layer in the left column of the AEM backend.

**DESIRED SOLUTION:**
Persist a bar like [Drag components here]-bar to enable users to click the (placeholder) bar if they want to change the fragments settings instead of clicking through the layers column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an AEM placeholder like this:

```
<sly data-sly-use.templates="core/wcm/components/commons/v1/templates.html" />
<sly data-sly-call="${templates.placeholder @ isEmpty = !properties.activatePopup}" />
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. This is the correct/best practice. Thanks René

Answer (score 0):

one solution would be use css and target the component with a min-width, this way it would show up on the screen and I am assuming by AEM backend you mean that you have to select the component from component tree, let me know if this works.

Comment: Adding a min-height will "show" on the frontend as well. I want the element to be completely hidden on frontend.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding a new div-element in the components html-file that only shows when the checkbox is false && wcmmode is in edit mode. See snippet below:

```
<!-- Div shows when checkbox (Enable pop-up) is false -->
<div data-sly-test="${!properties.activatePopup && wcmmode.edit}">
    <div class="pop-up-disabled">Click here to edit Popup</div>
</div>

<!-- Div shows when checkbox (Enable pop-up) is true -->
<div data-sly-test="${properties.activatePopup}">
    {POPUP_CONTENT_HERE}
</div>
```

Also added some css-styling.